# Is there a drinksafe Y-connector for garden hoses?

Tags: vegetables, watering

Most brass connectors contain lead. Can anyone point me to the most durable type of y-connector to buy to water my garden that will not inject any lead or harmful plastics into the water stream?

I am setting up an automatic irrigation system, so I have no way of dumping the first 2 litres of lead water first and then using the rest for watering the garden.

Comment: http://www.grainger.com/product/WESTWARD-Shut-Off-WP54014/_/N-lhl?s_pp=false

Comment: What are you using for pipe? Hoses? Most hoses give off carcinogens unless you get hoses meant for supplying water to recreational vehicles, motor homes and trailer homes.

Comment: This is the hose I am using: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0001MII88/ref=oh_details_o06_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1. It claims "Drinking-water safe due to F.D.A.-approved materials"

Comment: Not very trusting on the "FDA approved claim", is it actually hard marked along the length of the hose with NSF showing that it is NSF Certified or NSF Listed for drinking water use? Not very trusting after dealing with Chinese knockoffs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about lead or plastifiers leaking into the water, use food-grade stainless steel.

[http://www.amazon.com/Thogus-Tee-In-303-SS/dp/B0078RZ92M/ref=sr_1_4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0078RZ92M)